# How to make a div have a responsive height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, height, responsive

Basically:

1. I have a wrapper div that is 100% width and height.
2. Inside it is another div that is absolutely positioned and must follow the window height (with a little bit of margin at the bottom).
3. Inside this div is a ul list that will be always as high as the parent div. If it gets higher, it will become scrollable.

**This is what I'd like to achieve:**

[image]

```css
  .wrapper-location {
     position: relative;
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100%;
     background: #CCC;
     overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .box-locator {
     background: #f9f9f9;
     position: absolute;
      right: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 360px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        overflow: hidden;
     padding: 0;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
     z-index: 99999999;
    }
    
    .box-locator-listing {
     margin-left: 0;
     overflow-y: auto;
     height: 500px;
    }
    
     .box-locator-listing-item {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      list-style: outside none none;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      background-size: 50px 50px;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper-location">
    <div class="box-locator">
    
    <ul class="box-locator-listing">
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    </ul> 
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/ygrwPr

I've been pulling my hair and can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Why cant you use the ViewPort in order to handle responsiveness.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for. It can be done by adding height 100% to .wrapper-loctaion and height 90% to .box locator (add height 100% to html,body too). Now set top and bottom to 5% for .box-locator to center it vertically.

```css
  

    html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-location {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
}

.box-locator {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 360px;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    z-index: 99999999;
}

.box-locator-listing {
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 500px;
}

.box-locator-listing-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper-location">
    <div class="box-locator">
    
    <ul class="box-locator-listing">
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    <li class="box-locator-listing-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta at sem sit amet semper. Mauris vitae diam gravida, ultrices lacus sit amet, aliquam tortor.</li>
    </ul> 
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-bottom:50px i.e, equal to top:50px

```
.box-locator {
background: #f9f9f9;
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: 50px;
width: 360px;
border-radius: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
z-index: 99999999;
margin-bottom: 50px; //new property
}
```